# Limitar div html

Tags: php, html

Estou a imprimir um conteúdo de um array para dentro de uma div. O problema é que quando o array tem vários dados passa a div.

```
$titles = ""; 
foreach($array_resultados as $key =>$value){
    $titles .= "<div>".$value['title']."</div>"; 
}
```

E a minha div

```
echo" 
    <td class='cal_today'>

        <div class =divtoday>
            ".$titles."</div>
    </td>";
```

Queria imprimir todos os dados sem nenhum passar a div.

Comment: Qual das `div` é que passa?

Comment: é a div de cima, que passa para a div divtoday.

Comment: Se você [edit] a pergunta para esclarecer dúvidas, a pessoa que votou negativo pode reverter o voto.

Comment: Como passar a div?

Comment: Qual o motivo por trás de uma `<div>`para cada elemento do _array_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente sua pergunta, considere as seguintes divs:

```
<div class="um">
    <div class="dois">
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Com as seguintes propriedades css:

```
.um {
    max-height: 300px;
    display: block;
}

.um .dois {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    overflow: scroll;
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

**Explicando:** você tem que definir no seu css a div pai e a div filho (um e dois, respectivamente). Para fazer a div filho eu utilizei a propriedade **inherit**, que faz com que a div filho sempre herde o valor do max-height do pai.

**Veja a demonstração [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/rrvdgwdt/).**

Comment: Prefira `<style>` a um CSS separado, uma vez que a pergunta não inclui a tag css.

Comment: @Guill comentário estranho esse, pois o autor da resposta não disse onde o CSS deveria ser posto (se seria num arquivo separado ou entre `<style></style>`. Talvez fosse melhor reler a resposta com mais atenção.

Comment: Comentei há 5 meses. Não lembro por que comentei isso.